# Intellij javascript parser does not understand backticks?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

Backticks permit multiline strings in javascript 1.6+.  Is there a way to enable that comprehension?

This screenshot shows it doe not work out of the box.

[image]

Note: I have tried setting Javascript 1.6, 1.7 (and even 1.8 and 1.8.5..) and EcmaScript 6 and the syntax errors still remain.

[image]

**Update**  In response to one of the comments - I had mentioned already that EcmaScript 6 had been attempted.  Here is the screenshot for that one.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what JavaScript 1.7 is but Template Strings are ECMAScript 2015/2016

Comment: @AndreiNemes I had tried ECMAScript 6 as well